Gorilla Websocket WriteMessage leading Out of memory on using WriteBufferPool
I've upgraded to websocket with following upgrader
var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
    ReadBufferSize:    1024,
    WriteBufferPool:   &writeBufferPool,
    EnableCompression: false,
}

var writeBufferPool = sync.Pool{
    New: func() interface{} {
        return make([]byte, 1024)
    },
}

On using WriteBufferPool, memory consumption pattern is almost similar as using upgrader without WriteBufferPool.
I came across beginMessage method that initiates buffer as following. Here pool buffer is being typecasted to a private type that isn't exposed to create WriteBufferPool. I suspect if this is leading to buffer remaining unused.
if c.writeBuf == nil {
    wpd, ok := c.writePool.Get().(writePoolData)
    if ok {
        c.writeBuf = wpd.buf
    } else {
        c.writeBuf = make([]byte, c.writeBufSize)
    }
}

For reference, here is the code snippet that listens on a channel and writs to the socket
for data := range clientConnChannel {
    err = ws.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte(data.Raw))
    if err != nil {
        logger.ErrorWithCtx(
            ctx, "unable to write message to client", err,
        )
        break
    }
}

Can you help here if I'm missing something while using WriteBufferPool

The BufferPool documentation says

The type of the value stored in a pool is not specified.

Your application incorrectly assumes that the value stored in the pool is specified as []byte.
Fix your application by removing the sync.Pool's New function.
var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
    ReadBufferSize:    1024,
    WriteBufferPool:   &sync.Pool{},
    EnableCompression: false,
}


Is there a way to cap pool buffer size here ?
I'm trying to resolve a memory leak I'm experiencing in WriteMessage and I think keeping buffer pool uncapped won't help here.

@SanketBijawe, first you need to prove you actually have a memory leak (which is almost never the case). Part of the benefit of sync.Pool is that it allows GC to collect pooled values when not in use.

Hi @JimB, I'm streaming ~2.5MB stream per minute to ~1000 connections (40Kb per second per connection). Everything's working fine until WriteMessage. As soon as I start writing it to the connection on WriteMessage, memory keep on linearly increasing. Not sure "memory leak" is the right wording to use here.
Added the code snippet that calls WriteMessage to the description for reference.

@SanketBijawe, did you try the correct use of WriteBufferPool like in the answer? We can't really tell what else might be the problem without a lot more information -- it's possible what you are doing just takes a lot of memory and it will eventually stabilize.

Thanks @JimB. WriteBufferPool did worked here with &sync.Pool{}.
Though another issue with my code was heavy writes/sec was leading to goroutine being piling up waiting to send messages to clientConnChannel. This caused out of memory for the system.
